# How to add a empty column to a specific sheet in excel using panda?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file that contains 3 sheets (PizzaHut, InAndOut, ColdStone). I want to add an empty column to the InAndOut sheet.

```
path = 'C:\\testing\\test.xlsx'
data = pd.ExcelFile(path)
sheets = data.sheet_names
if 'InAndOut' in sheets:
     something something add empty column called toppings to the sheet
data.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Been looking around, but I couldn't find an intuitive solution to this.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Read in the sheet by name.
2. Do what you need to do.
3. Overwrite the sheet with the modified data.

```
sheet_name = 'InAndOut'

df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name)

# Do whatever

with pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, index=False)
```

See [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel) and [`pd.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas-excelwriter).